# Kali linux Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00

Tags: linux, crash, chroot, kernel-panic

I was running fsck for a disk in initramfs and after it finished, I wrote “exit” in terminal. After that, when booting in that drive, I still have the kernel panic screen. Tried to chroot into broken OS, but chroot seemed to not work (using live Ubuntu). I don’t have internet access on that machine for live OS, because Wi-Fi is broken and I have to use dongle with specific driver, so I cannot install anything in live Ubuntu. Please help. I add the picture of kernel panic [error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNdas.jpg)

Comment: See if you can boot to a terminal screen (option before Kali gets going). Then you need internet access to possibly repair.

Comment: How was Kali installed? You might try to salvage what you can from the file system, then reinstall Kali. If you *must* fix the drive with fsck first, then one option is to remove all partitions and the re-partition.